# Group generated by matrices with integers off the diagonal

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

I would like to know the subgroup generated by the following type of matrices.

$$A=\left(\begin{matrix}1&a\\ 0&1\end{matrix}\right)$$
and
$$B=\left(\begin{matrix}1&0\\ b&1\end{matrix}\right)$$

for integer $a,b\in\mathbb Z$.

Is there a way we can parameterize the full set of matrices $G\in\mathcal G=\langle A,B\rangle$?

The group operation is the matrix product

Comment: Since you are defining it as the group generated by $A$ and $B$, you don't need to check that it is a group.

Comment: @DerekHolt oh yes, I've updated the question by removing that part

Comment: My intuition is that the generated group is the special linear group $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$, i.e., of all matrices with determinant $1$.

Comment: @JeanMarie But $G$ is countable and ${\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb R})$ is uncountable! In fact $G={\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb Z})$.

Comment: @JeanMarie But the parameters a,b are only integers

Comment: You are perfectly right. I didn't notice the entries are integers... Corrected.

Comment: Like @DerekHolt said, It is $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: You will be interested by [this question and its answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2079111)

Comment: Group operation is matrix sum or matrix product?

Comment: @C.F.G matrix product

Comment: You should write "**sub**group" generated, not just group. The point of a subgroup is precisely that it inherits the law of some ambient group.

Comment: @YCor Ah yes, fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbf{Z}}$Here's a full proof that the subgroup $\Gamma$ generated by the matrix $u=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and its transpose $v$ is all of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\Z)$. Given a matrix $m=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$, we have
$$mu=\begin{pmatrix}a&b+a\\c&d+c\end{pmatrix},mu^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}a&b-a\\c&d-c\end{pmatrix},mv=\begin{pmatrix}a+b&b\\c+d&d\end{pmatrix},mv^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}a-b&b\\c-d&d\end{pmatrix}.$$
Write $N(m)=|a|+|b|$. We see that as soon as $|ab|>0$, one of these four matrices $m'$ satisfies $N(m')<N(m)$.

Hence, choosing $m$ that minimizes $N$ within $m\in m\Gamma$, we see that $N(m)=0$. Since entries in the first row are coprime (because determinant is $\pm 1$), the first row of $m$ is $(\pm 1,0)$ or $(0,\pm 1)$. Using the elementary operations above (which remain in $m\Gamma$), we can change $$(-1,0)\to (-1,1)\to (0,1),\quad (0,1)\to (1,1)\to (1,0),\quad (0,-1)\to (1,-1)\to (1,0).$$ Hence $m\Gamma$ contains a matrix with first row $(1,0)$, so, the determinant is $1$, this matrix has the form $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\c&1\end{pmatrix}$, namely equals $v^c$. Hence $v^c\in m\Gamma$, and since $v\in\Gamma$ this ensures $m\in\Gamma$.

Answer (score 1):

From the following reference

https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/SL(2,Z).pdf

we see the group $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb Z)$ is generated by the matrices

$$S=\left(\begin{matrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{matrix}\right)\quad\text{and}\quad T=\left(\begin{matrix}1&1\\0&1\end{matrix}\right)$$

We can see that the matrices given in the question are enough to generate $T$ and $S$ and hence they also generate the full group $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb Z)$.

$T$ can be identified as $T=A(a=1)$.

$S$ can be created using the matrices $A(a=-1)$ and $B(b=1)$, i.e.

$$S=A(a=-1)B(b=1)=\left(\begin{matrix}1&-1\\0&1\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}1&0\\1&1\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{matrix}\right)$$